# JavaScript - Get nested property's parent object

Tags: javascript, object

let's say I have a nested object like this:

```
let object = {
  another : {
    yet_another : {
      last_one : {
      some_property : [1,2,3]
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

I can access `some_property` like this:

```
object.another.yet_another.last_one.some_property;
```

And let's say I'm referring to this object in a variable:

```
var x = object.another.yet_another.last_one.some_property;
```

How can I tell what's the parent object of `some_property` if I only have access the `x` variable? is it even possible in JavaScript?

Comment: Commonly on stackoverflow, people arrive at a solution to a problem they are having an ask how to make their solution work. What you really need to do is ask how to solve your original problem, not how to make your "arrived at" solution work - so what's your original problem?

Comment: My original problem is simply too complex to show it here, I wanted to simplify it as much as I could but I think it's not well suited for a question here.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. An object doesn't have a "parent" per se. Observe:

```
let object = {
  another : {
    yet_another : {
      last_one : {
        some_property : [1,2,3]
      }
    }
  } 
};

let another_object = {
  foo: object.another.yet_another.last_one.some_property
};
```

Now what? The array is now equally a member of both objects.

Comment: I have a small app where I need o move around objects... Seems like I would just have to store my current "position" in this object in an array every time I go deeper into it's properties. that way I would be able to tell what's the parent just by reffering to some array...

Comment: @AleksanderCiecierski the solution to your actual problem sounds like it should be "don't move objects around". Instead of mutating objects, you should be creating entirely new ones.

Answer (score 0):

No, because when doing the following line;

```
var x = object.another.yet_another.last_one.some_property;
```

then you assign `x` to the value of `some_property`, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to an answer, the solution to your (actual) problem should be don't move objects around. Mutability can be very very expensive (eventually prohibitively) when it comes to maintaining an application.

Just create new objects:

```
const firstObject = {
   prop1: 'some value',
   prop2: {
      prop3: 'some value',
      prop4: [1,2,3,4]
   }
}

// don't do
const secondObject = { }
secondObject.prop2.prop4 = firstObject.prop2.prop4

// instead do
const secondObject = { ... }
const newObject = {
  ...secondObject,
  prop2: {
   ...secondObject.prop2,
   prop4: firstObject.prop2.prop4
  }
}
```

You may want to look into immutablejs.